# Can git break up changes by default?

Tags: git, git-checkout, git-stash, git-add, git-patch

I like to use the `-p` flag on several git commands, such as `add`, `reset`, `checkout`, and `stash`. But git groups somewhat contiguous changes together in the same hunk. I know that `s` breaks up the changes but is there another option I could pass to have git break them up by default wherever possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no command line options to accomplish what you want, nor is there a config option.  If there were a config option, I would expect to see it in the [`git-config` documentation](http://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-config) alongside the **interactive.singlekey** option.

Comment: I guess I'll just make do without it.

Comment: It sounds like an interesting feature request - you could ask about it on IRC or the development mailing list.